# can cloud9 debug html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, cloud9-ide

Is it possible to use debug in cloud9 for javascript in HTML? I know it's possible to debug node.js, but what if the javascript is in a `<script>` block in the HTML, or is being loaded from an external script?

This works in Webstorm, but you have to have a browser plugin, and the IDE and the browser (via the plugin) talk to each other.

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible to pop out the preview window into a separate browser tab where you can use the standard browser debug tools. Unfortunately there's a browser limitation that doesn't allow for Cloud9 to debug JS code within the preview window yet, but we're thinking of a workaround for this, similar to the solution you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 not provide a great visualization for debug but even so it doesn't a big problem.
You need open your application in another tab of the browser.

You have two ways:

1. If you use a "preview" mode for run an application, Cloud9 provide a URL that you can write in your bar browser.
2. If you use a server and this have the config for that it send your static files, when you run the server Cloud9 provide a URL in the console so you can write in your bar browser too. You need to consider the different routes in your server if it has not a single page application.

   Once you will open the application in your browser, you can make your debugging.